# Youtube video slideshow stop video on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I have a youtube video slideshow which gets populated with the use of a template:

```
    <script id="tFlowplayer" type="text/html">
        <div class="rv" id="{{name}}">
            <iframe class="{{id_v}}" width="575" height="323" src="{{id_v}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </script>
```

when I click on next or prev I need to stop the current youtube embedded video playing:

```
            <nav class="arrows">
                <button data-goto="prev" class="arrow arrow-left" rel="prev">Prev</button>
                <button data-goto="next" class="arrow arrow-right" rel="next">Next</button>
            </nav>
```

The following is the click event for the navigation, I guess this where the action will be happening:

```
    $('[data-goto]').on('click', function (evt) {
        var $this = $(this),
            where = $this.attr('data-goto'),
            video_id = $('[data-play]').attr('data-id');
        if (where === 'prev') {
            swiper.prev();
        } else {
            swiper.next();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `where` is keyword don't use it as variable.

Comment: Try looking at the api developers page:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: I need to figure out how can I check which video  is playing to use stopVideo()....